# Is there any equivalent median values to Estimated Marginal Means?

Tags: r, lsmeans

I am wondering if there is any sort of measure/R package/statistical tool to compute "balanced" median values for groups? I would like to do a pairwise comparison of these median values and plot them like one would with the emmeans package.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, I think the answer is no. However, you could do something that approaches that. For starters, you could specify `fac.reduce = median` in the `emmeans()` call. That will cause it to use the marginal medians rather than the marginal means.

However, that is not going far enough, because `emmeans()` summarizes a model, and most models predict the *mean*. So it would be desirable that the model try to predict the medians, or at least some robust measure of location, instead of the means. For example, fit the model using `MASS::lms()`.

It is still touchy because the covariance structure of the marginal medians is not well estimated by these methods. So I wouldn't be too literal in interpreting tests and CIs. If you can fit a Bayesian robust model, then the posterior sample of the marginal medians would be more trustworthy.

### Addendum

The more I think about this, the more I think this is fraught with problems, especially in terms of using the **emmeans** package. The package is quite heavily dependent on linearity of the estimation procedure; and the median is not a linear function of the data.

Just for sake of discussion, suppose we have some kind of unbalanced dataset with two factors $A$ and $B$ in a completely randomized design. For starters, just computing the marginal medians for $A$ and $B$ would be misleading for the same reason that the marginal means are -- which is where your question comes in.

So what can we do? Well, one thing that comes to mind -- parallel to what is done with EMMs -- is to compute the $A\times B$ (cell) medians, then compute the marginal medians of those. But note that even in a balanced experiment, that procedure will not yield the marginal medians of the data.

So another approach would be to use the cell counts as weights and compute weighted marginal medians: those would be a value such that half the weight goes to data above that value and the other half of the weight goes below. That procedure *would* yield the marginal medians if the data were balanced. But it is also completely outside of the algorithms used in the **emmeans** package. I do not think adding that capability to this package would be a good idea -- not that it wouldn't be a good thing, just that it'd be trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. Some other package -- hypothetically **emmedians** -- would be great to have.

Something akin to the first approach could be implemented in **emmeans**, but it would require a lot of care. First, we fit a model that fits medians or at least some sort of robust estimates of cell location. Second, use `regrid()` to remove the operability of any linear functions involved (`regrid()` will make the `linfct` slot equal to the identity matrix). Third, use the posterior estimates to obtain the desired marginal medians. (If not a Bayesian model, use `N.sim` in the `regrid()` call to create something akin to it.). Fourth, use `emmobj()` to wrap the results in an `emmGrid` object (or use `emmeans()` and then hack the resulting object to have the needed posterior estimates). Then you will have some kind of median-of-median estimates, and associated HPD intervals.

Comment: Thank you @Russ !

Comment: @jameshgrn Note I added to my answer